# Trying to set up proxies in Grunt and getting a 404 for index - Gruntjs

Tags: javascript, proxy, gruntjs

I am trying to set up proxies in my `Gruntfile`.  Here is my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;

  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    dirs: {
      js: ['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/libs/**/*.js'],
      html: ['app/index.html'],
    },
    connect:{
      development: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          middleware: function(connect) {
            return [proxySnippet];
          }
        },
        proxies: {
          context: '/users',
          host: '99.44.242.76',
          port: 3000,
          https: false
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true
      },
      html: {
        files: ['<%= dirs.html %>']
      },
      js: {
        files:  '<%= dirs.js %>',
        tasks: ['jshint']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', ['less', 'configureProxies', 'connect', 'watch']);
};
```

After I added in my middleware, I get a 404 for the `livereload` Chrome extension and then I get a 404 for the `index.html`.

[image]
  What am I doing to set this up wrong?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mjhamm75/gruntfile) is a `Gruntfile.js` where the proxy is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your gruntfile and replace this pattern to your
proxy part setting in your gruntfile

```
grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            proxies: [
                {
                    context: '/cortex',
                    host: '10.10.2.202',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false,
                    xforward: false
                }
            ]
        }
})
```

read this issue too https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy/issues/18

i thinks you dont set the hostname in options.

Comment: Adding the hostname didn't change anything.  It is when I add the middleware that I get my errors.